# C# SqlTransaction.Commit error when being called from Finalize

Tags: c#, sql, .net-4.5

I have a class in C# (.NET 4.5) which stored onto a SQL Transaction that has to commit (SQL Server 2012 Express).  I have implemented the `IDispose` interface which works perfectly to commit the transaction if I have the class instanced within a using statement.

However when someone makes a modular instance of this class there is no way to know when I will be done with the class.  Therefore, I implemented the classes finalize method which gets invoked just prior to the program ending.

However when I call my `Dispose()` method from finalize I get a `NullReferenceException` on the line that commits the transaction.  Any suggestions?

Code:

```
public class c : IDisposable
```

...

```
    ~c()
    {
        Dispose();
    }
```

...

```
    private bool _Disposed = false;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_Disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                //dispose managed ressources

                if (_SqlTransactionForLockingRecord != null)
                {
                    _SqlTransactionForLockingRecord.Commit(); // Throws runtime error if called from ~c();
                    _SqlTransactionForLockingRecord = null;
                }
            }
        }
        //dispose unmanaged ressources
        _Disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
```

Comment: Writing a finalizer is _hard_.  You can't do that.  (the transaction may already be collected)

Comment: Also, the entire point of the `Dispose(bool)` pattern is that the finalizer calls `Dispose(false)`.

Comment: This isn't a good idea.  Require client code to call a method that commits the transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.net gives you no warranty when your destructor/finalizer is called. Your transaction can already time out or be recycled (see comments). I believe you only need to call finalizers in some exotic cases when you need to free unmanaged resources. And even in such situations Dispose mostly works. So use Dispose.

I'm also not sure if commiting transaction even inside Dispose is a good idea. Logically dispose (and finalizer) are designed to free resources. Could be better to do it explicitly.

Comment: Thanks.  I was trying to be clever but it looks like I am going to have to bite the bullet and patch the code that uses this class.